# what is a spinor structure?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, spin-geometry

There are of course lots of definitions and references for this, but in the same way that, on a manifold $M$,

- a Riemannian metric is a section of positive definite symmetric bilinear forms on $TM$
- or an almost complex structure is a section $J$ of $\textrm{End}(TM)$ which is everywhere an anti-involution (*i.e.* $J_x^2 = - \mathrm{Id}_{T_x M} $)
- or an orientation is a non-vanishing section of $\Lambda^m TM$

is

a spin structure, a section of quadratic forms $Q$ on $TM$ (of type $(s,t)$) and a vector bundle $S$ so that $\textrm{End}(S) \simeq \textrm{C}\ell(TM,Q)$?

...or something of the like? any references where it may be stated in this fashion?

Comment: I think that Karoubi's book on K-theory  has a definition aling theseclines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chapter 9 of *Elements of Noncommutative Geometry,* by Gracia-Bondia, Varilly, and Figueroa, has this perspective on spin$^c$ and spin structures.

The way to think about this algebraically is that the module of (continuous, say) sections of a spinor bundle over a (compact, Riemannian) manifold $M$ is Morita equivalence bimodule for the algebras $C(M)$ and $Cl(M)$, where $C(M)$ is the algebra of continuous functions and $Cl(M)$ is the algebra of continuous sections of the Clifford bundle (formed using the Riemannian metric).  You can replace "continuous" with "smooth" here with no problems.

Comment: In your proposed definition R^k has no spin respectively spin^c structure unless k is divisible by 8 respectively 2.

Comment: @Dmitri: You're correct, I was being a bit imprecise here.  As Branimir points out, one should use the even sub-bundle of the Clifford bundle in case $M$ is odd-dimensional, and there are other considerations as well.  OP asked for a reference, so I was just briefly summarizing.

Comment: @MTS: As I pointed out in my answer, a much easier way is to define spin and spin^c structures as invertible bimodules between Cl(M) and Cl(F^dim(M)), where F is R respectively C.  If dim(M) is divisible by 8 respectively 2 then Cl(F^dim(M)) is Morita equivalent to F, and tensoring with the corresponding bimodule reduces the general definition to the one that you proposed.

Comment: @Dmitri, that's a nice way of looking at it.  As I said, I was just giving a brief summary of the basic idea presented in the reference that I listed.

Answer (score 15):

A spin structure on a real vector space V equipped with a real quadratic form μ
is an invertible bimodule (i.e., a Morita equivalence)
from Cl(V,μ) to Cl(**R**<sup>dim(V)</sup>,ν).
Here ν is the direct sum of dim(V) copies of the canonical
quadratic form on **R**.

A spin<sup>c</sup> structure on a complex vector space V equipped with a complex quadratic form μ
is an invertible bimodule
from Cl(V,μ) to Cl(**C**<sup>dim(V)</sup>,ν).
Here ν is the direct sum of dim(V) copies of the canonical
quadratic form on **C**.

Note that spin and spin<sup>c</sup> structures form
a category instead of a mere set, just as we would expect.

Of course, these definitions immediately extend
to vector bundles, with the obvious requirement
that invertible bimodules form bundles themselves.

A spin or spin<sup>c</sup> structure on a smooth manifold
is a spin or spin<sup>c</sup> structure on its real
or complex tangent bundle.

Answer (score 9):

Just to elaborate a bit in explicitly differential-geometric terms on MTS's answer, which refers to [certain results of Plymen's](http://www.theta.ro/jot/archive/1986-016-002/1986-016-002-008.pdf) originally restated in terms of Morita equivalence (via the dictionary given by the Serre–Swan theorem), let $M$ be a compact orientable Riemannian manifold, and let $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$ be the finite rank Azumaya bundle given by the complexification of the Clifford bundle $\operatorname{Cl}(M)$ if $\dim M$ is even, and by the complexification of the even subbundle of the Clifford bundle if $\dim M$ is odd. Then $M$ is *spin*$^\mathbb{C}$ if and only if there exists an irreducible $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$-module, that is, a Hermitian vector bundle $\mathcal{S} \to M$ (i.e., *a* spinor bundle) such that $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M) \cong \operatorname{End}(\mathcal{S})$.

Now, if what you care about are specifically *spin* manifolds, one can endow $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$ with a canonical $\mathbb{C}$-linear anti-involution, and hence equip the dual bundle $\mathcal{E}^*$ of a $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$-module with the structure of a $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$-module. It is then , that $M$ is actually *spin* if and only if there exists an irreducible $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$-module $\mathcal{S} \to M$ such that $\mathcal{S} \cong \mathcal{S}^\ast$ not only as Hermitian vector bundles, but also as $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$-modules—this is, then, *the* spinor bundle for its corresponding spin structure. Indeed, by the anti-unitary isomorphism $\mathcal{S} \cong \mathcal{S}^\ast$ of Hermitian vector bundles defined by the Hermitian metric, together with a little bit of care, one can recognise such a unitary isomorphism of $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$-modules as nothing else than the charge conjugation operator on spinors in mild disguise.

Comment: Clarification for posterity: what Plymen calls an "irreducible $\operatorname{\mathbb{C}l}^{(+)}(M)$-module" is actually the stronger notion of a "pointwise irreducible" module. What is irreducible is the quotient of the module by the maximal ideal in $C(M)$ corresponding to $x$, for each $x\in M$.